# What lifetime to use with Iterator for a hierarchy of `Rc`s?

Tags: rust, iterator, lifetime

I've got a Rust struct that represents a hierarchical data structure and each struct contains a `Vec<Rc<Self>>` that creates the hierarchical structure.  I want to create an iterator that iterates over `Rc`s to every member of the hierarchy, starting with a given node.  The `Node` struct has a lifetime parameter `'a` because the entire hierarchy refers some `&'a str`s from a text document that the whole hierarchy is based on (contained inside `NodeDetail<'a>`).

```
pub struct Node<'a> {
    pub detail: NodeDetail<'a>,
    pub children: Vec<Rc<Self>>,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {
    // Returns an iterator over `Rc`s to all the children
    pub fn iter(&self) -> Box<(dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>> + 'static)> {
        let mut ans:Box<(dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>> + 'static)> = Box::new(std::iter::empty());

        for c in self.children.iter() {
            ans = Box::new(ans.chain(std::iter::once(c.clone())));
            ans = Box::new(ans.chain(c.iter()));
        }

        ans
    }
}
```

With this attempt, I'm getting this error:

```
error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime for lifetime parameter `'a` due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/model/updm/impl_common.rs:23:40
   |
23 |             ans = Box::new(ans.chain(c.iter()));
   |                                        ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime `'a` as defined on the impl at 5:6...
  --> src/model/updm/impl_common.rs:5:6
   |
5  | impl<'a> super::UpdmCommon<'a> {
   |      ^^
note: ...so that the types are compatible
  --> src/model/updm/impl_common.rs:23:40
   |
23 |             ans = Box::new(ans.chain(c.iter()));
   |                                        ^^^^
   = note: expected `&UpdmCommon<'_>`
              found `&UpdmCommon<'a>`
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the expression is assignable
  --> src/model/updm/impl_common.rs:23:19
   |
23 |             ans = Box::new(ans.chain(c.iter()));
   |                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   = note: expected `Box<(dyn Iterator<Item = Rc<UpdmCommon<'a>>> + 'static)>`
              found `Box<dyn Iterator<Item = Rc<UpdmCommon<'a>>>>`
```

I think it's somehow confusing the lifetime that the `Node` struct is generic over with a lifetime specific to the iterator.  I'm cloning the `Rc`s so the `Item` of the iterator is owned and has a `'static` lifetime.  I think the iterator itself should also be owned, which would make it `'static`.  I first tried `Box<dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>>>`, then added the `'static` annotation to try to fix the first errors I got.  Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to tie the lifetime of the value you're returning from `iter()` to `&self` and you need to cast the boxed iterator to a trait object.

```
use std::rc::Rc;

pub struct NodeDetail<'a>(&'a str);

pub struct Node<'a> {
    pub detail: NodeDetail<'a>,
    pub children: Vec<Rc<Self>>,
}

impl<'a> Node<'a> {

    // Returns an iterator over `Rc`s to all the children
    pub fn iter(&'a self) -> Box<(dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>> + 'a)> {
        let mut ans = Box::new(std::iter::empty()) as Box<dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>>>;

        for c in self.children.iter() {
            
            ans = Box::new(ans.chain(std::iter::once(c.clone())));
            ans = Box::new(ans.chain(c.iter()));
        }

        ans
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

I figured it out.  I do my best troubleshooting immediately after I ask for help.  Kind of like how I do my best email proofreading after pressing send.

It turns out that I needed `Box<(dyn Iterator<Item=Rc<Self>> + 'a)>` which makes sense now that I think about it because the iterator can't outlive the original `&'a str`s that the whole hierarchy depends on.